# Qt Quick3D: draw a 3D line between 2 points

Tags: qt, qt6, qtquick3d

I am using the new QtQuick3D from Qt6. I need to draw a line between 2 points, but didn't find a function dedicated for this. Therefore I decided to use a basic cylinder that I can scale and rotate. The scaling works as intended, but the rotation has some issues.

```
Node {
    property vector3d center
    property vector3d scaleCylinder
    property vector3d eulerAngles

    Model {
        id: line
        position: center
        source: "#Cylinder"
        scale: scaleCylinder
        eulerRotation: eulerAngles

        materials:
            DefaultMaterial {
            diffuseColor: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

I compute the rotation using the Eigen library, via an angle axis to retrieve the Euler angles. The cylinder axis is in the Y-axis when displaying it.

```
AngleAxis angleAxis(const PointType vec) {

    double angle;
    VectorType axis;

    PointType a = PointType({0, 1, 0});
    PointType v = normalize(vec);

    axis = point2vector(normalize(cross(a, v)));
    angle = acos(dot(a, v));

    return AngleAxis(angle, axis);
}

void setEulerAngles() {
    AngleAxis rotation = angleAxis(target - entry);
    VectorType angles= rotation.toRotationMatrix().eulerAngles(0, 1, 2);
    eulerAngles = QVector3D(float(angles[0] * 180.0 / M_PI), float(angles[1] * 180.0 / M_PI), float(angles[2] * 180.0 / M_PI));
}
```

Did I make a mistake when computing my Euler angles? Should I use another technique, like quaternions? Maybe there is even a simpler solution I don't know about.